# How to deploy the setInterval loop using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am doing the sample code https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions#1. In this sample code, I want to modify the code to show the history event text on Friendly Chat instead of input messages. I added my code into the file **index.js** in folder **functions**. When I deployed the functions, I want to display the history event text (18:59:44 Mega market An Phu CLOSED), then I need to trigger the web app Friendly Chat by enter the message (open or close) in the **Message** (see the figure below).
[image]

To display the history event text repeatedly, I used the function **setInterval** (the following code).

```
// The code of the web app
// My code added 
const db = admin.firestore();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const https = require('https');

var status;

const url = 'https://online.mmvietnam.com/trung-tam/mm-an-phu/';

const interval = setInterval(function () {
var currentdate = new Date();
var hours = currentdate.getHours() + 7 ;

if (hours >= 24) {
  hours = hours - 24 ;
}

var datetime =  hours + ":"
    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":"
    + currentdate.getSeconds() ;

const agent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get(url, { httpsAgent: agent }).then(response => {
    var html = response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    var menu = $('.vertical-wrapper');
    var text = menu.find('.text-title').html();

    if (text !== null) {
       status = 'OPEN';                 
    }
    else {
       status = 'CLOSED';
    }
 });
async function quickstartAddData(db) {
  // [START firestore_setup_dataset_pt1]
  const docRef = db.collection('messages').doc('mmAnPhu');
  await docRef.set({
        name: 'Thu',
        text: datetime + ' ' + 'Mega market An Phu' + ' ' + status,
        profilePicUrl: 'CamThu', 
        timestamp: datetime 
 });    
}
quickstartAddData(db);
}, 60000);
```

In the code above, the infor about **profilePicUrl** and **timestamp**, I do not the exactly infor, I only use them to consistent with the other code of the web app. I only need the **text: datetime + ' ' + 'Mega market An Phu' + ' ' + status**.

My problem is: the **web app** only display the history event text about 10 times, then it stop displaying. If I want to see the next history event text, I must to enter the input messages in **Message** (above figure) again.

How I make the function **setInterval** run continually to see the history event text displaying continually on **Friendly Chat**?

Thank you for all your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions are designed to run for relatively short periods of time after a certain event happens. They cannot be used to run continuous processes. Specifically: Cloud Functions [can run no longer than 9 minutes](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#timeout).

So that explains exactly why your interval stops after about 10 times: it has reached the maximum time that a Cloud Function can be active.

Given that you're trying to run a piece of code every minute, you can [schedule a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run every minute. That will not only solve the functional problem, but it will also be much cheaper - and you're not paying for the (typical majority of the) time in your current execution that the code it idle.

Comment: I appreciated your guidance.